# Feeds between min and max timestamp Instagram

Tags: api, timestamp, instagram

I am getting users feeds list from Instagram using the following API call and displaying to users.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed/?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

But I want to fetch the feeds only which is created with in particular time limit (from min_timestamp to max_timestamp).

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed/?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&MAX_TIMESTAMP=1437224400&MIN_TIMESTAMP=1437220800
```

But there is no min or max timestamp parameters available for this request based on Instagram API documentation - https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

We can use min_id and max_id to fetch feeds between particular id range instead of using timestamps. But how can i find the starting min_id for particular timestamp? I have searched lot in google and failed to get the solution for this problem. Is it possible to do this? Please anybody share your thoughts and solution if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find out a solution to this ?